# How to get all selected options from <select multiple=multiple> and store it in ms access using jdbc and servlets?

Tags: java

I created a web project in Netbeans and simple html page with a drop down menu that upon submission should store the options selected from the drop down in ms access (DBMS) via JDBC. My problem is that access is only inserting the first option selected and disregarding the other options from the drop menu that I have also selected.

```
<form action="seat" method="get" class="seatselection">
    <h3>Select your seat(s):</h3>
    <select multiple="multiple" name="op">
        <option>Seat Number</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>16</option>
        <option>17</option>
        <option>18</option>
        <option>19</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Servlet: seat.java

```
Statement smt = conn.createStatement();
int seat = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("op"));
int c = smt.executeUpdate("INSERT into TableTest(SeatNumber) values("+seat+")");
out.println("<h3>" + "Record Entered Successfully!!" + "<h3>");
conn.close();
smt.close();
```

Comment: Hi, we need code to be able to help you. E.g., how does the dropdown look like?

Comment: Hi @andy. See the above. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getParameterValues("op")`. See also https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues(java.lang.String)

`getParameter("op")` returns the first value only.

```
   for (String parameterValue : request.getParameterValues("op")) {
      int seat = Integer.parseInt(parameterValue);

      Statement smt = conn.createStatement();
        
      int seat = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("op"));
        
       
        int c = smt.executeUpdate("INSERT into TableTest(SeatNumber) values("+seat+")");
        out.println("<h3>" + "Record Entered Successfully!!" + "<h3>");
        
        smt.close();

    }
    conn.close();
```

You can improve your code by using a prepared statement:

```
   PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT into TableTest(SeatNumber) values(?)");
   for (...) {
       ...
       stmt.setInt(seat);
       int c = stmt.executeUpdate();
       ...
   }
   stmt.close();
   conn.close()
```

Then your code is safe against SQL injection. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: @Rubzmahn if my answer solved your question please check it as the solution. Thanks :-)